# Create names for a list of data frames based on a value in that data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to use a unique value in a column to name another column in a list of data frames

```
library(data.table)

a <- c("BZ", "BZ", "BZ", "US", "US", "US")
b <- c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)
c <- data.table(a, b)
d <- split(c, c$a)
```

I am wanting to then drop column A and use the unique value from column a to name column B

For example, if I just had one dataframe with one a value, I could do this:

```
c <- subset(c, a == "BZ")
x <- unique(c$a)
setnames(c, "b", x)
```

Is there a way to perform this on a list of data frames?

Comment: @Parfait it is from `data.table`

Comment: Please be aware of **not** redefining function `c` with an arbitrary value. This will cause problems in the long run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` of `data.table`s, extract the first element of 'a' (as there is only one `unique` element and set the names of the column with `setnames`

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- lapply(d, function(x) setnames(x[, .(b)], x$a[1]))
```

Or we could have used a subset of columns before `split`

```
d2 <- split(c[, .(b)], c$a)
Map(setnames, d2, names(d2))
```

---

If we don't want to drop the column

```
lapply(d,  function(x) setnames(x, "b", x$a[1]))
```

Or use `Map`

```
Map(setnames, d, old = "b", new = names(d))
```

Comment: Thank you!  I went with the first option.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but I think it accomplishes what you're looking for:

```
a <- c("BZ", "BZ", "BZ", "US", "US", "US")
b <- c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)
c <- data.table(a, b)
d <- split(c, c$a)

e <- lapply(d, function(x) {
  names(x)[grepl('b', names(x))] <- unique(x$a)
  x
})
```